# d2: difference between allocating array through new and assigning array literal

Tags: d

Consider following code:

```
class C {
    immutable(double[][]) data;

    this() {
        immutable(double[])[] blocks = [];
        immutable(double)[] block;

        foreach (x; 0 .. 5) {
            block = [];

            block ~= 0.1 * x;
            block ~= 1.0 * x;
            block ~= 10.0 * x;

            blocks ~= block;
        }

        this.data = blocks;
    }
}
```

It's simplified "dry extract" of my code, that fills array of arrays with values. This code snippet works as expected, but as I'm new to D, I'm not sure if I'm doing it right.

Does the assigning of array literal actually allocate memory in right way or it's better to use something like `new double[0]`? Aren't there some caveats while reassigning same literal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning to empty literal has the same effect as assigning to null. It doesn't allocate any memory. The allocation happens when you concat into "block". That results in reallocation of the array three times, I think if the values are statically known it can be optimized further. Anyway, I'd probably pre-allocate "block" with 3 elements just once, then assign the respective elements each iteration and concat into "blocks" (it will perform a copy here). I'm expecting you don't know the value of "x" statically. If you do, you can as well statically initialize the capacity for "blocks".

Comment: Thank you - now it's clear why concat to uninitialized array worked too. Unfortunately, I don't know the size of "block" too, because it's read in realtime from user-provided file, but I think it could be possible to allocate array in chunks and extend it on demand.

Comment: The loop will not for each append, there is a capacity which is in "powers of 2 up to a page of data."

Comment: Check out std.array.Appender (http://dlang.org/phobos/std_array.html#Appender); it offers the extension on demand.

Answer (score 1):

Assigning `[]` doesn't allocate anything. It's the same as assigning `null` or not initializing the dynamic array at all. It makes it so that the array has a `length` of `0` and `ptr` which is `null`. It's only when an array's `ptr` property is non-zero that it has any memory which is allocated to it.

As it stands, you might as well just move `block`'s declaration to the line where you assign it `[]` and get rid of the assignment. As it stands, you're needlessly reusing the variable over and over. Since, it's only used within the loop, that's the only place that it should exist.

If you want to reduce the odds of having extra reallocations of the array as you're appending to it, then either use [`reserve`](http://dlang.org/phobos/object.html#reserve) or [`std.array.appender`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_array.html#appender).

You really should read [this article](http://dlang.org/d-array-article.html) or arrays in D. It should help you a lot with your understanding of how arrays work in D.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to `reserve` - I thought about reinventing a wheel through changing .length to some bigger value and changing it back to original value, so array could expand without reallocation up to requested limit.

Comment: Appender worked nice - tastes much like `''.join()` in Python. Reading your article.

Comment: @modchan As the article explains assigning a larger length and then a shorter one doesn't help. In fact, it _guarantees_ that the next append will result in a reallocation. It has to do with how slices work. You can't append into another slice, and setting the length to a greater value like that makes the runtime think that there's a slice there, even if there isn't anymore after you reduced the length.